# How to search by text in SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to search by text in `SQL Server Integration Services` packages using `T-SQL` statement (or other language)?

I want to check if certain table is used in any package as I am going to drop it - if the table is used I need to edit the package.

Could you advice?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the .dtsx files, they are just XML so you could use a simple text search of the files, something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153750/how-to-search-a-string-in-multiple-files-and-return-the-names-of-files-in-powers

Comment: How to locate the `.dtsx` files? Is there a column in the database pointing their location?